# sed + how to be sure that sed replaced the value correctly

Tags: linux, bash, sed, stdout

here is a nice example how to replace the value on match key on file

```
str="192.2.34.40:2181,192.2.34.34:2181,192.2.34.32:2181,192.2.34.52:2181,192.2.34.53:2181"
sed -i "s~^[[:space:]]*zookeeper\.connect.*~zookeeper.connect=$str~" /opt/server.properties
```

example

```
more /opt/server.properties
zookeeper.connect=192.2.34.40:2181,192.2.34.34:2181,192.2.34.32:2181
```

after we run the sed command we get

```
more /opt/server.properties 
zookeeper.connect=192.2.34.40:2181,192.2.34.34:2181,192.2.34.32:2181,192.2.34.52:2181,192.2.34.53:2181
```

but we can be sure that value is replaced correctly ?

we can of course just add verification as:

```
sed -i "s~^[[:space:]]*zookeeper\.connect.*~zookeeper.connect=$str~" /opt/server.properties
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "sed failed" && exit 1
```

but not sure if std output that gives 0 , is covered all failures

Comment: Hello, a bit not related to the question itself, but you have in your str twice ":2181:," instead of ":2181," , which seems odd if we are talking  url:port   entries

Comment: to have sed itself exit with a specific (... non-0 ! ) code if it managed to replace: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965681